# Are questions about implications of surgery procedures on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some may have questions about the implications of a surgery.

Here are a couple of examples:

- Will hysterectomy affect posture or shape of the stomach?
- What are the consequences (if any) on cosmetic jaw surgery on the bite?

These may be lame examples and in any case I wanted to ask whether ***in general***, are questions about implications of surgery procedures on-topic?

It seems that they may not be (based on [this list](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) which is why I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think these types of questions are on-topic as long as they are **not too broad** and **not too personalized**. I like your examples because they ask very clear questions. Basically, you are asking "Can something happen to {body part} during {name of surgery}?" I think that these are good, clear questions that aren't too broad.

If someone instead asked "What are the risks of {name of surgery}?" it would be closed. That question would be way too broad¸and possibly even too personalized, because surgeries can have different overall risks on different people.

So, if your question is specific, I say it should be on-topic.

Comment: in general, are questions asking for a list considered to be broad?